# Mysql :- insert data in two difference database

Tags: mysql, insert

I want that when i fire query from my java application in one database. same time that thing insert in remote DB. How we configure mysql from that.

I think so for that i require clustering  in DB. that is my thinking plz give some suggestion. I not backup trick.

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: need to do a better job at answering questions it would appear. Please make sure you go back to your previous ones and accept the ones that were of help.

Answer (score 1):

You know the way you connect to and query one database?

Do that twice, just have different host/db names in the connection strings.

Comment: Or, assuming the log-in works on both DBs, just fully-qualify them. ;-)